# Matrix Notation: Detect if Argument is Greek Letter (or Command)

Tags: math-mode, bold, greek, sans-serif, boldsymbol

I am trying to implement a matrix/vector notation that makes simple bold vectors with

```
\newcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}
```

and I used to do the same for matrices (with a command `\mat`). However, I want to change this notation to use a sans-serif font for matrices like this:

```
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\bm{\mathsf{#1}}}
```

But this breaks for greek letters as my font does not have sans-serif greek letters (I assume that's the problem). Therefore, I want to detect whether the argument is a greek letter (or, more generally whether it is a latin letter) and therefore switch back and forth between simple `\bm` and `\bm\mathsf` similar to this:

```
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\iflatin{#1}{\bm{\mathsf{#1}}}{\bm{#1}}}
```

I could fall back to just listing all latin letters, but I wonder if there is a nicer way of doing this. I also though of things like `\@ifnextchar`, but that obviously does something different.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your font?

Comment: I think it's Charter – I'm using this document class: https://github.com/tudace/tuda_latex_templates

Comment: OK, but there are so many files. Please add a minimal example.